# What is the proper syntax for passing an array of objects and looping through it in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

I am trying to create the following functionality

1 array of questions gets passed as a prop in a vue link like so

```html
<router-link
          :to="{
            name: 'finder_step',
            params: {
              id: 2,
              questions: [
                {
                  id: 'q1',
                  body: 'one'
                },
                {
                  id: 'q2',
                  body: 'two'
                }
              ]
            }
          }"
        >
          Step 2
</router-link>
```

where the questions prop is an array of objects with an id and body text. However, the issue I am stuck on is that my output then becomes  `[ "[object Object]", "[object Object]" ]`

What I am understanding is that my object is getting converted into a string at some point. What I dont understand is why, and what the proper syntax I need to use is.

Here is how I loop over my array in the vue file.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>ID: {{ id }}</p>
    <p>Question: {{ questions }}</p>
    <li
      v-for="question in questions"
      :key="question.id"
    >
      {{ question.body }}
    </li>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: { type: String, default: '' },
    questions: {
      type: Array,
      id: String,
      body: String
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what happens if you remove `id: String, body: String` and set `default: () => []` in your child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route params are intended to be strings in the route's URL for [dynamic path parameters](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), so Vue Router automatically [encodes them](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/91649a560af361e465a725a4d956a8dc120cec37/src/router.ts#L476-L483).

One workaround is to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on any params that are not strings/numbers (i.e., `questions` in this case):

```html
<router-link
    :to="{
      name: 'finder_step',
      params: {
        id: 2,              
        questions: JSON.stringify([
          {
            id: 'q1',
            body: 'one'
          },
          {
            id: 'q2',
            body: 'two'
          }
        ])
      }
    }"
  >
    Step 2
</router-link>
```

Then [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the prop in your component as a [computed property](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties):

```js
export default {
  props: {
    questions: Array
  },
  computed: {
    computedQuestions() {
      if (typeof this.questions === 'string') {
        return JSON.parse(this.questions)
      } else {
        return this.questions
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use the computed prop in your template:

```html
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="question in computedQuestions"
    :key="question.id"
  >
    {{ question.body }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-obj-array-in-router-params?file=src%2Fviews%2FFinderStep.vue)